# Gridview not showing records?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq

I just attached linq data to gridview it is not showing row ?

```
DataDataContext db = new DataDataContext();
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
        BindData();
}

private void BindData()
{ 
    var source = from n in db.Names
                 select n;

    gridSample.DataSource = source.ToList<Name>();
    gridSample.DataBind();'
}

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="panelGrid" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gridSample" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="First Name">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" Text='<%Bind("FirstName") %>' />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblFirstName" Text='<%Eval("FirstName") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Last Name">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server" Text='<%Bind("LastName") %>' />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblLastName" Text='<%Eval("LastName") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date of Birth">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDOB" runat="server" Text='<%Bind("DOB") %>' />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblDOB" Text='<%Eval("DOB") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
   </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: You have write it wrong Use `<%# Eval("DOB") %>` to read them. Note the `#`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
List<Name> source = (from n in db.Names select n).ToList();

        gridSample.DataSource = source;
        gridSample.DataBind();'


<asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FirstName") %>' />
```

Comment: Thanks this worked but now gridview only show two rows, while i am getting 12 row from db.

Comment: Add a breakpoint on your source variable, and see how many it has in its collection

Comment: And i guess calling your table Users would be a better practice then just Names

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 private void BindData()
    {

        var source = from n in db.Names
                     select n;

        gridSample.DataSource = source;
        gridSample.DataBind();'
    }
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Set the property

AutoPostBack = True

for the GridView. Since it is inside the UpdatePanel.